# What is the difference between an object, and a tkinter object assigned to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to understand a program using an OOP approach, but that doesn't seem to be going to well.

I'm able to follow the code below (that I found online) quite a bit, but I have some question about ***the relationship between `root` and `my_gui`*** (found below the class definition).

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyFirstGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title("A simple GUI")

        self.label = tk.Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
        self.label.pack()

        self.greet_button = tk.Button(master, text="Greet", command=self.greet)
        self.greet_button.pack()

    def greet(self):
        print("Greetings!")

root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I know that the label and button objects in the init method each go into the master object (which is the root object), but what confuses me is differentiating `my_gui` and `root` after the init method has been executed.

1. After the init method of the class executes, does `my_gui` and
   `root` become one and the same thing, or is `root` now a subset of
   `my_gui`?
2. If they are essentially the same being after the init function
   executes, then there is no need for the `my_gui` object, is there?
3. What exactly is `self.master = master` doing?

I guess what I really want to know is the **relationship between `my_gui` and `root`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"What is the difference between an object, and a tkinter object assigned to it?"*

I assume by that you mean the part:

```
root = tk.Tk()
my_gui = MyFirstGUI(root)
```

Here `root` isn't exactly *assigned* to an object but rather is passed as an argument *for* an object. Then that argument is assigned as an *attribute* to that object. Which *does* mean that `root` now *is* a subset of `my_gui` as far as the python hierarchy is concerned.

`my_gui` object makes use of `root` object in the way that it, first of all, assigns it as an attribute, `self.master`, and then it creates widgets as children to it.

> *"If they are essentially the same being after the init function executes, then there is no need for the `my_gui` object, is there?"*

They are *not* the same, they are the instances of unique classes.

You can think of `MyFirstGUI` as one constructor class for GUIs. In the above case, it is constructing for `root` but it can also construct for some(`Toplevel`) widgets `root` may later on have:

```
my_toplevel = tk.Toplevel(root)
my_gui2 = MyFirstGUI(my_toplevel)
```

It could've even constructed for `Label` and/or `Button` widget that `root` currently has, which are also attributes to `my_gui`, if `master.title(...)` line was removed.

> *"What exactly is `self.master = master` doing?"*

That line takes a method variable (`master`) and assigns it as an attribute to every particular object created with `MyFirstGUI` class. It is *then* available for modifying/using under all of the sub-scopes in `MyFirstGUI`(and the scope its object, `my_gui`, is available). An example of its use would be that in the `__init__` there is a label created using the line:

```
self.label = tk.Label(master, text="This is our first GUI!")
```

while that wouldn't be possible under another method, for example `greet,` *if* `self.master = master` wasn't there. As in having:

```
def greet(self):
    print("Greetings!")
    self.label2 = tk.Label(master, text="Greetings!")
    self.label2.pack()
```

and calling `my_gui.greet()` would return `NameError: name 'master' is not defined` error while having:

```
def greet(self):
    print("Greetings!")
    self.label2 = tk.Label(self.master, text="Greetings!")
    self.label2.pack()
```

and again calling `my_gui.greet()` would work perfectly as expected.

Comment: Thanks! That was a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The only relationship between `root` and `my_gui` is that `my_gui` uses `root`. Otherwise they are simply two variables referencing two different objects.

> After the init method of the class executes, does my_gui and root become one and the same thing, or is root now a subset of my_gui?

Neither. root is not a subset of `my_gui`, it's just one of many things that `my_gui` knows about. It is not a subset of `my_gui`, it is merely *used* by `my_gui`.

> If they are essentially the same being after the init function executes, then there is no need for the "my_gui" object, is there?

They are not essentially the same. `my_gui` is an instance of `MyFirstGUI`, `root` is an instance of `Tk`. They are two separate things, and in this specific example, both are required.

> What exactly is "self.master = master" doing?

It's remembering the parameter that was passed in to it, so that it can refer to it later.